# "Games Request only are available for games" - alternative .appInvite

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk

Hello i always use the function() below to invite people to an app:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(
        {
           method: 'apprequests',
           message: 'Check out Givvia!'
        },
        function(response) {
           log(JSON.stringify(response));
           httpService.logAppRequest(response);
        },
        function() {
            log('Could not send Message');
        }
    );
```

Unfortunately, this function not work anymore for normal App which is NOT A GAME.

I was looking around and i found the these code:

```
var fbOptions={
          url: "URL LINK",
          picture:"PICTURE LINK"
        };
     facebookConnectPlugin.appInvite(fbOptions,
             function(postId){
                console.log("success");
            },
             function(error){
                console.log("failure");
                console.log(error);
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
    );
```

Now, i'm able to invite friends but i do not get the response i was get with 'aprrequest'. here i get the refer and the receiver ID of facebook. do anyone know how to get these information with **appInvite**?

Comment: How to invite people is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Comment: it doesn't work anymore.. i try all explanations on facebook

Comment: What doesn't work?